# Counterintuitive remediation cost scale within SEI CERT Coding Guidelines for priority

Tags: secure-coding, programming, code-review, vulnerability-assessment

The [SEI CERT Coding Guidelines](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/seccode/SEI+CERT+Coding+Standards) assign a priority to each rule, formed from the product of three factors: severity, likelihood, and remediation cost. Each of these three factors is assigned a value from 1-3, and the highest priority formed by such a product is 27.

While the severity and likelihood correspond to my intuition (assigning a 3 to highly serious consequences, and a 3 to a likely vulnerability), I find the value scale for the remediation counterintuitive. A remediation value of 3, is described as the most *inexpensive* rule to apply; permitting the use of automatic detection, and automatic correction. Yet this would correspond to a 27 (3x3x3): i.e. the *highest* possible priority. Surely one should assign maximum priority to the most severe, most likely rule, which also has the highest cost to comply with? After all, the cost might correspond to time when staff levels are low.

The relevant section of the SEI CERT Coding Guidlines wiki is [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/How+this+Coding+Standard+Is+Organized).

Comment: Highest severity has nothing to do highest cost of fixing. You can have a critical issue fixable with one click or a nearly irrelevant one that would require weeks of work and investments.

Comment: Yes, but it's the derivation of a *priority* value - from the *multiplication* of severity; likelihood; and remediation cost I'm questioning.

Comment: Remediation cost is wrong to exist in a severity formula, at least not in a direct manner. If you want to include cost in it, you will have to take in consideration possible costs of damage of not doing it.

Comment: Your 3 3s should be: severity (amount of damage), chance (% of occurrence) and everything else (here you can include the cost part too).